# How to get column id using row index

Tags: jquery

Suppose I know row index of any row of my table can I use this to find column id of that row?

I just need column id using this index information.

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the row number, you can access to the column with `getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0]`,

```js
document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "HELLO"
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
    row 1
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
    row 2
    </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```